# Remotely Execute PHP File to Create JSON File

Tags: php, json

I am having an issue where I am trying to remotely execute a php file using ssh. The php file is supposed to make a json file and also echo "hi". It echo's "hi" but never creates the JSON file.

All files and directories are set -rwxrwxrwx or drwxrwxrwx. Only username on both servers are "root". PW for app server is pre-saved on the main server.

**Main Server**

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'php /test/example/makeconfig.php'
```

**Application Server**

makeconfig.php

```
<?php

$return_arr = array('ID' => 50, 'password' => "testpassword");


$json_data = json_encode($return_arr);
file_put_contents("config.json", $json_data);

echo "hi";

?>
```

I run the code from the main server in the console. It will output "hi" on the main server's console screen but when I go over to the application server it doesn't create the file "config.json". If I run the command

```
php /test/example/makeconfig.php
```

on the application server it will output "hi" and also create the config.json file.

I am just not sure why the config file will not create if the php file is executed from a remote server.
Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: I removed that tag that said "DO NOT USE" in capitals in its description.

Comment: The script itself doesn't fail, since you got the echo, but maybe `file_put_contents` failed. Have you tried to check its result? It returns an integer or `false` depending on the outcome. Also, have you tried specifying a full path so you know for sure the file is stored in the right directory?

Comment: When you run the commands and they work, are you running them as root from root's home directory?

Comment: Does the php script have permissions to write in its working directory? Have you tried checking if the return value of file_put_contents() `=== false`? Can you run in an environment that displays errors, or logs them?

Comment: Just an advice, you should not allow root to be used through ssh since it is an vulnerability. I think the problem is that when you execute `php /test/example/makeconfig.php` the file is being created in the directory where you execute the PHP file, so most likely the file is created but not where you expected it to be but in the home folder. To be sure that the file is created check if `file_put_contents()` doesn't return `false` as well. Also try `cd /test/example/` and then `php makeconfig.php`

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thank you for all the help but I fixed it in between me checking the post. I fixed it by changing "file_put_contents" as an absolute path.

```
<?php

$return_arr = array('ID' => 50, 'password' => "testpassword");


$json_data = json_encode($return_arr);
file_put_contents("/test/example/config.json", $json_data);

echo "hi";

?>
```

It has been challenging me for over a month now. Something so small. Thank you for the comments. I appreciate it a lot.